# error 500 when updating data

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I want to update the atributte ad_stat from the table name advert but i get error:

```
  500 Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is javax.servlet.ServletException:org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is null"
```

here is the code for update the data

```
@ApiOperation(value = "deactiveAd", nickname = "deactive Ad")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "ads/deactive", produces 
= "application/json")
@ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")
    })
    public Response deactiveAd(@RequestPart(name = "adsId", required = true) 
int ad_id){
            Response response = new Response();
            DbHandler db = new DbHandler();
            if(db.getResult() == 0){
                    try{
                            String sql = "UPDATE advert SET ad_stat = false 
WHERE ad_id = "+ad_id+";";
                            if(!db.execute(sql)) {
                            response.setStatus("0");
                    }else{
                            response.setStatus("3");
                    }
                            db.closeStatement();
                            db.closeConnection();
                    }catch(SQLException e) {
                            response.setStatus("1");
                    try{
                            db.closeConnection();
                            db.closeStatement();
                    }catch(SQLException e1) {

                    }
                    }
            }else{
            response.setStatus(String.valueOf(db.getResult()));
    }
    return response;
}
```

the data type for ad_stat is boolean, and i try to false it

Comment: Check how you send the data. Try to change from GET to POST. Add 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' to the header of data you send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "ads/deactive", produces = "application/json")
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "ads/deactive", produces = "application/json",Content-Type="multipart/formdata")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add enctype to your form.

```
<form enctype=”multipart/form-data”></form>
```